# wpa_supplicant issue

Tags: linux, wifi, wpa-supplicant

We are using `wpa_supplicant` utility v2.2 for Wlan.

Below is the configuration for the router:

```
Mode: WEP
Password: 12345678

Mode: WPA
Password: 1122334455
```

The router's current mode is WEP and we are trying to connect to a router with password of WPA which is `1122334455`. Doing so, `wpa_supplicant` gives signal `CTRL-EVENT_CONNECTED`.

As we are just waiting for that event, our GUI application shows it is connected though we are passing the wrong password.

Is there any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this error is occurring because you are using different encryption modes, because if you will use WEP mode you must use WEP on both routers as devices and not in other ways different. Since each mode operates differentially from one another, because if you use WEP mode, you can not use WAP as well as WPA2, ie safe mode encryption network should be one, WEP is used, then it should be the mode used WEP s in all devices, if you are using WAP, you should therefore use WAP on all devices and so on!

Comment: My router and device is using same mode which is WEP. Router mode is WEP and device mode is also WEP. when connect to router with WEP password then everything works find  but when i try to connect to wrong password ( WPA's password ) then it should send CTRL-EVENT_DISCONNECTED signal but currently it is sending CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED signal.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you're using WEP mode is clear that it will not work if you are entering a WAP password because passwords must be the same on both router / device that is:

Router ...:
    Mode: - WEP Password: 12345678

Device ..:
    Mode: - WEP Password: 12345678

What you can do to help improve security if you can not configure both router / device with same security mode that is trying to increase the level of password security to a higher level, as posted earlier in another post you can use the tool md5pass to assist you in creating a stronger and prepared.